# Reflection of Circularly-Polarized Light

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, angular-momentum, electrons, reflection

A mirror reflecting circularly-polarized light will be imparted with twice the angular momentum of the incoming beam (the handedness is reversed, momentum is conserved). How can this be explained from a classical perspective? How are the electromagnetic waves interacting with the electrons in the mirror in order to create the torque?

Comment: No, you're mistaken. The *handedness* switches, but the direction of rotation is the same, since the direction of travel is also flipped. The mirror is not imparted with any angular momentum.

Comment: Your convention as to whether circularly polarised light is left or right handed depends on a choice of either having the light coming towards you or away from you.  So you must change your viewing position when light is reflected. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization#Reversal_of_handedness_by_reflection